# Source code of shell commands

Tags: c, linux, shell

How do I write a function of some commands of shell (UNIX) in C language? E.g what is the source code of the exit function? How can we write its function in C lanugage?

OR

For example; exit command: Implement the exit command that quits the shell. (how to do this/ from which link/book ; a concept can be taken?)

and similarly For pwd command: Implement the pwd command that prints the user’s current working directory.

Comment: `exit` is necessarily a shell built-in.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the source code, you can find it at the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) page.

If you're asking how to exit a shell from within a program, the `exit` command line command is a bash builtin, there's no `/bin/exit`.  You'd have to find the appropriate PID and kill it.  The `exit` builtin probably performs some cleanup and then uses `exit(int)`.

If you want the source code for the shell builtins, look at the [bash source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are many shells which are open-source or free software, so you can download them and study their source code. A simple example is [sash](http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/), a more complex example is [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/)

The [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) function (called from the shell's `exit` [builtin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin)) is inside [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/), it runs the registered handlers (e.g. by [atexit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) etc..) and then call the [_exit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) system call.

[system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are mostly handled by the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) whose source code is on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)

I strongly recommend reading a good textbook on operating systems, like e.g. *Modern Operating Systems* by Andrew Tanenbaum, or *Understanding Operating Systems* by Ann McHoes &, Ida M. Flynn.

I also recommend reading a good Posix/Unix programming book like e.g. [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/)  by Rochkind & the late Stevens

Comment: which text book would u prefer to read?? i want to implement some commands of SHELL (UNIX) in C language like exit, pwd, ls etc.

Comment: I gave some references in my edited answer. And I really suggest you to follow all the links I gave you. At last, I don't understand why you are asking this question? Are you coding a tiny shell as a home work?

Comment: yes; the task is to create tiny shell ! and only a few days left ! hardly a week. so couldn't get a proper idea to do all of these. so 1st step is to executing these commands and to write some codes of taking input and so..

Comment: No, first step is to understand why most of these commands are builtin, and what is a syscall.

Comment: thats what; i want to know ; from where, i can have these concepts. the question posted above is one of da part of assignment. moreover i have to do also this : The prompt should have the following format:
<user>@<host> <cwd> > (with space at the end)
Here, <user> should be your login name, <host> the host name you are logged in to, and <cwd> the current working directory... so dont have a clear idea from where to start.

Comment: Start to make a shell with just `cd` and `echo` as builtins and perhaps the ability to run a simple program without arguments (like `/bin/ls`). But you still have to read things ... Perhaps looking into  the source code of *sash* could help also...